# How to force a file with a different extension to preview as a text file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I added a Python (`py`) file in Google Drive. I cannot preview it (but the main trouble is that Google won't search in it) even if it is a UTF8 text file. I can add it with the `txt` extension, but I would prefer to keep it as it is. Can I force the preview? If not, can I change the type somewhere to make Google Drive understand that is just a plain text file?

One partial solution is to add the python file with the supplementary txt extension (like <`filename>.py.txt`) and then remove it.